# how to create a pagination for a photo gallary?

Tags: php, pagination, photo-gallery

I have retrieved a list of photos using webservice and added their addresses to an array.
I need to show the photo gallary along with pagination. As most of the examples are related to databases, I could not find any pagination sample or tutorial for this purpose

Comment: So you need a paging interface? Maybe this helps: http://www.google.com/?q=php+pager

Comment: @geremy, you are a wise guy :D read the question again I have already said that most of the samples are related to DBs.

Comment: You want play with arrays.. So, why don't you do this at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk). It will create the "pages" for you out of the array. Then [count](http://php.net/count) the number of pages and create a pagination by looping from 1 to the number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like working?

```
$a = array(
    '/gallery?id=1',
    '/gallery?id=2',
    '/gallery?id=3',
);
$c = count($a);
@ $page = intval($_GET['page']);
if (!$page || $page <= 0) $page = 1;
if ($page > $c)           $page = $c;
// print_r($page);
foreach ($a as $i => $gallery) {
    printf("<a href='%s&page=%d'>Page %d</a>\n", $gallery, $i+1, $i+1);
}
// current
print 'Current: '. $a[$page - 1];
```